# Combination of swipe gesture and click button in a same Activity

Tags: java, android, button, swipe

I am a beginner with android Studio. I want to implement in a Activity : a swipe capture and the use of one button. In order to do that, I used a class which inherits from the class Gesture Detector :

```
public class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector {

    private final static int DELTA_MIN = 50 ;

    public SwipeGestureDetector (final FriendActivity context){
        super(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener () {

            public boolean onFling (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY){

                float deltaX = e2.getX()- e1.getX();

                if(Math.abs(deltaX) >= DELTA_MIN){

                    if (deltaX <0){
                        context.onSwipe(SwipeDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
                        return true ;
                    }
                    else {
                        context.onSwipe(SwipeDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
                        return true ;
                    }
                }
                return false ;
            }

        } );
    }

    public static enum SwipeDirection {
        LEFT_TO_RIGHT, RIGHT_TO_LEFT
    }

}
```

Here the code of the Activity where the "swipe" and button are implemented ( The code is simplified) :

```
public class FriendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button btnDelete ;


    private SwipeGestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend);

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(btnBestListener);
        gestureDetector = new SwipeGestureDetector(this);

    }

    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    }


    private View.OnClickListener btnBestListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ACTION WITH THE BUTTON
        }
    };


    public void onSwipe(SwipeGestureDetector.SwipeDirection direction) {

        switch (direction) {
            case LEFT_TO_RIGHT:
                //ACTIONS WHEN I SWIPE FROM THE LEFT TO THE RIGHT
                break;

            case RIGHT_TO_LEFT:
                //ACTIONS WHEN I SWIPE FROM THE RIGHT TO THE LEFT
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

The swipe gesture works very well however the click button is unusable. I think it is due to the fact that the motionEvent is "captured" by the GestureDector. I hope that my explanations were clear. Could you help me to fix this problem ? If you have a solution could you explain it in a very simple way because I am starting with Android Studio and Java.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: what you want to do with the `Button`? want to capture click event ?

Comment: The corresponding layout displays some informations on the users of the app. The swipe action is used to make a "slideshow" (different text view are updated : name, surname, email,...). The button is used to delete a user from the database. It 's my first application, it is just a trial to learn android studio. Thank you for you answer :)

Comment: So what is not working in button ? is click event not triggering ?

Comment: Yes due to the capture of the swipe action with the motion event, the click does not work :/

Comment: check my answer. @Haennor

Answer (score 0):

You missed `findViewById()`. You are setting the `listener` to a null `button`.

Check below code:

```
private Button btnDelete ;


    private SwipeGestureDetector gestureDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend);
        btnDelete = findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(btnBestListener);
        gestureDetector = new SwipeGestureDetector(this);

    }
```